# Calling method in post delayed

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

i am trying to stop recording after some time span and not getting idea how to call method of stop recording (new to android )

here is the what i am trying...
(both method are called in onClick in Xml)

```
  public void startRecording(View v) {

    Log.d(TAG, "startRecording()");
    // we need to unlock the camera so that mediaRecorder can use it
   // this.camera.unlock(); // unnecessary in API >= 14
    // now we can initialize the media recorder and set it up with our
    // camera
     flipCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     captureImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(this.camera);

    camera.unlock();
    this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    this.mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);

    this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    CamcorderProfile camcorderProfile_HQ = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
    this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile_HQ);
     this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.initFile().getAbsolutePath());
     this.mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(60000); // Set max duration 60 sec.

    this.mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.cameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
   try {
        this.mediaRecorder.prepare();
        // start the actual recording
        // throws IllegalStateException if not prepared
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.recording, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // enable the stop button by indicating that we are recording
        this.toggleButtons(true);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopRecording();// how to call stop here so that i can stop after 60 seconds
            }
        }, 60000);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to prepare MediaRecorder", e);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.cannot_record, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        this.releaseMediaRecorder();
    }
}
```

and i am calling stop method on button click however i also want to add 60 seconds delay so that media recorder stop.

```
 public void stopRecording(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "stopRecording()");
    assert this.mediaRecorder != null;
    try {
        this.mediaRecorder.stop();
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // we are no longer recording
        flipCamera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        captureImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.toggleButtons(false);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // the recording did not succeed
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to record", e);
        if (this.file != null && this.file.exists() && this.file.delete()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Deleted " + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        return;
    } finally {
        this.releaseMediaRecorder();
    }
    if (this.file == null || !this.file.exists()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "File does not exist after stop: " + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Going to display the video: " + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoPlaybackActivity.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        System.out.println("########Uri is: " + Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.putExtra("fromClass", "");
        intent.putExtra("file_name", videoName);
        intent.putExtra("data_type", "video");
        intent.putExtra("expiry_time", "");
        super.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Error log-

```
 05-15 13:51:34.050: W/SurfaceView(4877): CHECK surface infomation creating=false formatChanged=false sizeChanged=false visible=false visibleChanged=true surfaceChanged=true realSizeChanged=false redrawNeeded=false left=false top=false
05-15 13:51:34.410: E/MediaPlayer(4877): error (1, -2147483648)
05-15 13:51:34.420: E/MediaPlayer(4877): Error (1,-2147483648)
05-15 13:51:34.420: D/VideoView(4877): Error: 1,-2147483648
05-15 13:51:37.400: D/Camera_Activity(4877): stopRecording()
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877): Failed to record
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at com.ss.chat.Camera_Activity.stoprecording(Camera_Activity.java:350)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at com.ss.chat.Camera_Activity$6.run(Camera_Activity.java:297)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
05-15 13:51:37.400: W/Camera_Activity(4877):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 13:51:37.410: D/Camera_Activity(4877): Deleted /mnt/sdcard/Movies/MyVideo/VID_20140515_135037_13.mp4
```

Comment: your stopRecording method takes a View instance as parameter.

Comment: write the handler in your button click listener.

Answer (score 1):

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopRecording(v);// how to call stop here so that i can stop after 60 seconds
            }
        }, 60000);
```

Comment: Okay just pass the view to the stopRecording() as I mentioned

Comment: you can use the View v(parameter of startRecording) since you have called stopRecording() within the method startRecording()

Comment: hmm i am doing let me check what happens?

Comment: You will have to make the view final in startRecording parameters.

Comment: can you post the crash log?